# Regex to match text and a specific number

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex which can match the following conditions.

- It always starts with **"someId":[** and ends with **]**.
- It must contain the number 25 within the square brackets.
- There may be numbers before and after number 25
- The numbers are separated with a comma (,) apart from the last number

For example:

```
"someId":[25]
"someId":[25,27]
"someId":[1,4,25]
"someId":[1,4,25,27,30]
```

I have the following regex which works, however I was wondering if theres a better way to do it which isn't as greedy.

```
"someId":\[(\d{1,2},)*?25,?(\d{1,2},)*?(\d{1,2})?]
```

Comment: Is `"someId":[255]` good or bad? If bad, as I suspect, you can use word boundaries, perhaps. Could you also supply more counter-examples, please. Oh, and what language? Different languages have different features, so please add an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2):

a bit simplified:

```
"someId":\[(\d+,)*25(,\d+)*\]
```